# Vector3.ToString "rounds" decimals after build

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, vector, coordinates, resolution

I'm trying to get very precise Input.mousePosition in Unity3D with `Input.mousePosition.x.ToString("F4");` and in the editor everything works fine. I get 4 decimal signs exacly how I need it. However, after I build the app, I get x.0000 all the time.

What important is, that, in the editor, I don't get zeroes only when I choose precise resolution and not the aspect ratio or Free Aspect. I was trying to play around with build resolution settings, for example disabling all aspect ratios, setting exact resolution, windowed/fullscreen mode. Nothing helps so far.

It seems like the built app sort of disables inbetween pixel position, and I have no idea why.

I know that there are plenty of questions and info on vector3 decimals, but my problem is mostly about display resolution (inbetween pixel coordinates) in Unity. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Sounds like it is not a problem with Vector3 but rather with the value you are getting there. Is the inbetween pixel value with a precision of 4 decimals that essential for your app?  If you think about it: usually the mouse simply **is** exactly on a certain pixel and in between values .. honestly I'm not sure why they even exist within UnityEditor

Comment: @derHugo Yes, this precision is essential unfortunately. I agree that usually the mouse is (logically supposed to be) on exact pixel, but Input.mousePosition is indeed Vector3 with at least 6-9 decimal signs. I'm sure that it's possible to obtain these precise values because I'm getiing them in debug.log in the editor.

Comment: But you have `ToString("F4")`, which is to format the float with 4 decimals, right? Have you tried just doing `ToString()` and seeing what you get? Are you `Debug.Log`ing with the ToString("F4") or just `Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition.x)`?
EDIT: I misread, I thought the `x.0000` meant to say that you got 4 decimals and that was too few.

Comment: It seems VERY weird that the float would be rounded down to closest integer `x.0000`... Are you sure that you're not doing something in code to round it before printing it?

Comment: There would be endless bug reports if floats suddenly became `int` when building the game

Comment: @Fredrik Schön The code is of course the same in the editor and in the build, and in the editor it's not rounded, why it is in the app I have no idea. Not a single error while debugging and/or while building. I know, it's very very weird that after building I get zeroes. From that I assume that the problem is not in the code but rather something with display resolution, cause there are zeroes in the editor as well if I don't set exact resolution instead of Free Aspect.

Comment: It's just a small app that gets display coordinates on mouse click and sends them to external CSV file.

Comment: There is no reasonable expectation that `Input.mousePosition` will continue to produce subpixel values in the editor or will begin to do so in any platform in the future. You would probably be better off redesigning your input to consume `Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X")` and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y")` if you need input that doesn't round to pixels.

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks a lot! Will try and report back here